# Python Spirit Animal Quiz

Tags: python, function

I am being tasked with building a program that selects a spirit animal based off of the selected answers for 2 questions, using a minimum of 4 functions outside of main(). I have gotten the questions to work correctly but then it just stops. The code I used is below.

```
def main():

    colors()    

    foods()

    results()

def colors():

    colors = float(int(input('What is your favorite color of the following choices:\n\nPress 1 for Pink\nPress 2 for Blue\nPress 3 for Green\n\n')))

    if colors != 1 and colors != 2 and colors != 3:
        colors = float(int(input('Invalid option. Try again:\n')))
                          

def foods():

    foods = float(int(input('Nice! Now what is your favorite food of the following choices:\n\nPress 1 for Steak\nPress 2 for Chicken\nPress 3 for Seafood\n\n')))
                 
    if foods != 1 and foods != 2 and foods != 3:
        foods = float(int(input('Invalid option. Try again:\n')))

def results():

    if (colors == 1) and (foods == 1):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Eagle)

    elif (colors == 1) and (foods == 2):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Wolf)

    elif (colors == 1) and (foods == 3):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Horse)

    elif (colors == 2) and (foods == 1):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Deer)

    elif (colors == 2) and (foods == 2):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Tiger)

    elif (colors == 2) and (foods == 3):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Lion)

    elif (colors == 3) and (foods == 1):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Turtle)

    elif (colors == 3) and (foods == 2):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Hawk)

    elif (colors == 3) and (foods == 3):
        print('Your spirit animal is...', Bear)

def animals():

    Eagle = print('Eagle\n\nYou are strong, brave, creative, and insightful')
    Wolf = print('Wolf\n\nYou have a high sense of loyalty and communication')
    Horse = print('Horse\n\nYou embody independence and freedom')
    Deer = print('Deer\n\nYou are gentle, strong, and love unconditionally')
    Tiger = print('Tiger\n\nYou are strong, beautiful and independent')
    Lion = print('Lion\n\nYou are a brave and outspoken leader')
    Turtle = print('Turtle\n\nYou are wise and patient')
    Hawk = print('Hawk\n\nYou are a symbol of clarity and truth')
    Bear = print('Bear\n\nYou are strong, courageous and wise')



main()
```

Comment: *colors* and *foods* are names of functions. You cannot compare a reference to a function with an int

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem as to why the functions stop running after completing the questions. I can make it work without defining functions, as a straightforward program. But the assignment requires 4 functions and I am struggling to understand how to make them work.

Comment: It stops running because when you call *results()* none of the conditions are met. Therefore it won't print anything. The program is actually terminating normally - it's just that the logic is flawed. Also, are you aware that *print()* returns None? Think about that and your code in the *animals()* function

Comment: Why are you converting to floats?

Comment: @Max They don't even need to be int as they're not used in a numerical context. Just use strings

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid cumbersome conditional checks by building a dictionary and using it rather like a database.

Something like this (prompts changed for brevity):

```
spirit_animals: dict[tuple[str, str], tuple[str, str]] = {
    ('1', '1'): ('Eagle', 'You are strong, brave, creative, and insightful'),
    ('1', '2'): ('Wolf', 'You have a high sense of loyalty and communication'),
    ('1', '3'): ('Horse', 'You embody independence and freedom'),
    ('2', '1'): ('Deer', 'You are gentle, strong, and love unconditionally'),
    ('2', '2'): ('Tiger', 'You are strong, beautiful and independent'),
    ('2', '3'): ('Lion', 'You are a brave and outspoken leader'),
    ('3', '1'): ('Turtle', 'You are wise and patient'),
    ('3', '2'): ('Hawk', 'You are a symbol of clarity and truth'),
    ('3', '3'): ('Bear', 'You are strong, courageous and wise')
}

one_two_three = {'1', '2', '3'}

def get_colour() -> str:
    while (colour := input('What is your favourite colour 1) Pink, 2) Blue, 3) Green: ')) not in one_two_three:
        print(f'{colour} is invalid')
    return colour

def get_food() -> str:
    while (food := input('What is your favourite food 1) Steak, 2) Chicken, 3) Seafood: ')) not in one_two_three:
        print(f'{food} is invalid')
    return food

def result(colour: str, food: str):
    print('Your spirit animal is', *spirit_animals[(colour, food)])

def main():
    colour = get_colour()
    food = get_food()
    result(colour, food)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `not in '123':` is a bug. An input of 12 will be considered valid for example

Comment: @aloha_erich You are absolutely right. Thank you. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I forgot to mention that we could not include any global variables and still had to have a minimum of 4 functions NOT including the main. After troubleshooting using the answers provided here combined with my own work, I ended up with the proper results I was looking for. Final results are below:

```
def colors():

    color = float(input('\nWhat is your favorite color of the following choices:\n\nPress 1 for Pink\nPress 2 for Blue\nPress 3 for Green\n\n'))

    while color != 1 and color != 2 and color != 3:
        print('\nInvalid option. Try again:\n\n')
        color = float(input())

    return color;                          

def foods():

    food = float(input('\nNice! Now what is your favorite food of the following choices:\n\nPress 1 for Steak\nPress 2 for Chicken\nPress 3 for Seafood\n\n'))
                 
    while food != 1 and food != 2 and food != 3:
        print('\nInvalid option. Try again:\n\n')
        food = float(input())

    return food;

def animals():

    ColorReturn = colors()
    FoodReturn = foods()


    if (ColorReturn == 1) and (FoodReturn == 1):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Eagle\n\nYou are strong, brave, creative, and insightful.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 1) and (FoodReturn == 2):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Wolf\n\nYou have a high sense of loyalty and communication.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 1) and (FoodReturn == 3):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Horse\n\nYou embody independence and freedom.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 2) and (FoodReturn == 1):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Deer\n\nYou are gentle, strong, and love unconditionally.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 2) and (FoodReturn == 2):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Tiger\n\nYou are strong, beautiful and independent.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 2) and (FoodReturn == 3):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Lion\n\nYou are a brave and outspoken leader.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 3) and (FoodReturn == 1):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Turtle\n\nYou are wise and patient.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 3) and (FoodReturn == 2):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Hawk\n\nYou are a symbol of clarity and truth.')

    elif (ColorReturn == 3) and (FoodReturn == 3):
        print('\nYour spirit animal is...Bear\n\nYou are strong, courageous and wise.')

def results():

    print('\nEnd of results.')

def main():

    print('Find your spirit animal!')

    animals()

    results()



main()
```